# what's the event that a device connect to solace and subscribe to solace?

Tags: events, subscribe, solace

We wanna make a function that once a device connect and subscribe to solace,we will publish a topic to it.we want to know what's the event that a device connect to solace and subscribe to solace?which chapter we can refer to.Thanks

Comment: It would depend on your use case, but have you considered a [request/reply](http://dev.solacesystems.com/get-started/java-tutorials/request-reply_java/) pattern for your device connection / boot strapping or possibly a [Subscription Manager](http://dev.solacesystems.com/blog/obo-managed-subscriptions-solace/) pattern. This could simplify your application which wants to publish a topic to newly connected devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a client connects to Solace, there will be a CLIENT_CLIENT_CONNECT event raised in the event log. If you would like to see the more information about this event and a list of all other events, you can refer to the SolOS-TR Event Reference Guide available on the Solace Developer Portal here:

https://sftp.solacesystems.com/Portal_Docs/#page/SolOS-TR_Event_Reference_Guide/doc_start_event_ref.html#

There is no event generated in the event log when a client subscribes to a topic, as this can become very verbose. However, there is an option to publish a subscription event over the message bus. These events will be sent out on the Message VPN in which the event occurred. For more information about this, you can refer to Chapter 4 of the Message Bus and Events Management guide, available on the Solace Developer Portal here:

https://sftp.solacesystems.com/Portal_Docs/#page/Message_Bus_and_Events_Management/Subscribing_to_Message_Bus_Events.html#